# Get hourly data with gaps from midnight till now

Tags: mysql

I'm using the code below in order to generate data from midnight till now.

```
SELECT CONCAT(Hour, ':00-', Hour+1, ':00') AS Hours, IFNULL(COUNT(product_id), 0) AS `total_count`
FROM     clicks
  RIGHT JOIN (
               SELECT  0 AS Hour
         UNION ALL SELECT  1 UNION ALL SELECT  2 UNION ALL SELECT  3
         UNION ALL SELECT  4 UNION ALL SELECT  5 UNION ALL SELECT  6
         UNION ALL SELECT  7 UNION ALL SELECT  8 UNION ALL SELECT  9
         UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
         UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15
         UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17 UNION ALL SELECT 18
         UNION ALL SELECT 19 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 21
         UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23
  )      AS AllHours ON HOUR(clicked_at) = Hour
WHERE   ( clicked_at BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND NOW()  OR clicked_at IS NULL ) AND clicks.site='awesome-site.com'
GROUP BY Hour
ORDER BY Hour
```

I need the code to return something like

```
Hours     total_count
----------------------
0:00-1:00     19
1:00-2:00     2
2:00-3:00     0
3:00-4:00     0
4:00-5:00     0
5:00-6:00     1
6:00-7:00     0
7:00-8:00     0
8:00-9:00     0
9:00-10:00    4
10:00-11:00   2
11:00-12:00   0
12:00-13:00   17
13:00-14:00   1
```

The issue is that the query above is return is returning data with gap in the Hours column; something like:

```
 Hours     total_count
    ----------------------
    0:00-1:00     19
    1:00-2:00     2
    5:00-6:00     1
    9:00-10:00    4
    10:00-11:00   2
    12:00-13:00   17
    13:00-14:00   1
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right join is the correct approach, but you are using columns from `clicks` table in the where statement. Instead put the filter in `on`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Hour, ':00-', Hour+1, ':00') AS Hours, IFNULL(COUNT(product_id), 0) AS `total_count`
FROM     clicks
  RIGHT JOIN (
               SELECT  0 AS Hour
         UNION ALL SELECT  1 UNION ALL SELECT  2 UNION ALL SELECT  3
         UNION ALL SELECT  4 UNION ALL SELECT  5 UNION ALL SELECT  6
         UNION ALL SELECT  7 UNION ALL SELECT  8 UNION ALL SELECT  9
         UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
         UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15
         UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17 UNION ALL SELECT 18
         UNION ALL SELECT 19 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 21
         UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23
  )      AS AllHours ON HOUR(clicked_at) = Hour
  and   ( clicked_at BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND NOW()  OR clicked_at IS NULL ) AND clicks.site='awesome-site.com'
GROUP BY Hour
ORDER BY Hour
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. unfortunately I got  `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON ( clicked_at BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND NOW() OR clicked_at IS NULL ) AND ' at line 14`

Comment: @Lomse, sorry. I didn't notice the existing `on` statement, just change the 2nd `on` to `and`

Answer (score 1):

An easy potential solution would be to just have a separate table with all the hours in a day (since the only problem seems to be having 0 entries that fall within certain hours):

```
Hours
-------------
0:00-1:00
1:00-2:00
2:00-3:00
...
22:00-23:00
23:00-24:00
```

Then `JOIN` that to the other table you have, I think basically all the other stuff you do should work with this such as the `IFNULL` and `WHERE   ( clicked_at BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND NOW() ...`